# Prolog arithmetic syntax

Tags: prolog, clpfd

How to define `a` as a integer/float number ?

I want to find the results of `a+b+c+d=10` where `a,b,c,d` is integer and `>=0`.

Comment: Have added a solution to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple, modern, pure Prolog, non-CLP-library solution:

```
range(X):-
        member(X,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).

ten(A,B,C,D):-
        range(A),
        range(B),
        range(C),
        range(D),
        10 =:= A + B + C + D.
```

Comment: Is there a more simple way to represent 0~10?I'm worried when the problem's domain is 0~100...

Comment: SWI Prolog has the ``between/3`` predicate. ``between(0,100,X)`` will successively bind X to 0..100 inclusively.

Comment: `between/3` for **gnu-prolog** can be found in [GNU Prolog compatibility layer](http://www.david-reitter.com/compling/prolog/compat_gnu.pl) , btw. related stackoverflow question : [Prolog Compatibility Layers - available programming libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151675/prolog-compatibility-layers-available-programming-libraries)

Comment: This answer inspired me to [one more related question, here is interlink :).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175258/prolog-generating-list-of-numbers-fitting-given-range)

Answer (score 5):

with SWI-Prolog you can use CLP(FD) library

```
1 ?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
%  library(error) compiled into error 0.00 sec, 9,764 bytes
% library(clpfd) compiled into clpfd 0.05 sec, 227,496 bytes
true.

2 ?- Vars=[A,B,C,D],Vars ins 0..10,sum(Vars,#=,10),label(Vars).
Vars = [0, 0, 0, 10],
A = 0,
B = 0,
C = 0,
D = 10 ;
Vars = [0, 0, 1, 9],
A = 0,
B = 0,
C = 1,
D = 9 ;
Vars = [0, 0, 2, 8],
A = 0,
B = 0,
C = 2,
D = 8 ;
Vars = [0, 0, 3, 7],
A = 0,
B = 0,
C = 3,
D = 7 ;
...
```

Comment: Well, first you define 4 variables, then defining domains for variables (from 0..10) then adding constraints (sum of all vars = 10), last statement (label(Vars)) causes search (by backtracking) for all possible variables values.

Comment: Are ins ,#= keywords of clp?I never see them in prolog before.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [GNU-Prolog](http://gprolog.org/) piece of code with constraint solving over finite domains :

```
$ gprolog
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
ten(A,B,C,D) :- fd_domain([A,B,C,D],0,9999999), 10 #= A + B + C + D.
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

```
| ?- ten(A,B,C,D), fd_labeling([A,B,C,D]).
```

As you can see, it solves problem of **big ranges** like 0-9999999

```
A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 10 ? ;

A = 0
B = 0
C = 1
D = 9 ? ;

A = 0
B = 0
C = 2
D = 8 ? ;
...
```

P.S. Thanks for Przemysław Kobylański for his [blog with clear, very nice Prolog examples](http://prolog-clp.livejournal.com/), where I've found inspiring examples.

P.P.S. When playing with finite domains, you might like to use [fd_set_vector_max/1](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~haemmerl/gprolog-rh/doc/manual056.html#toc257) . In above case it's not needed, but depending on constraint might be usefull - more details when Gnu-Prolog operates on ranges, when on vectors of possible values, [can be found at manual "Finite domain solver and built-in predicates - Introduction"](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~haemmerl/gprolog-rh/doc/manual055.html)